# Can't set properly the format of a Kendo Grid date column sent to the controller

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have seen same question here: [Set the format of a Kendo DateTimePicker date sent to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285881/set-the-format-of-a-kendo-datetimepicker-date-sent-to-the-controller)
However the given answer doesn't solve my problem.

Briefly: I have a Kendo grid with such column:

```
model: {
  id: "Id",
  fields: {
    Id: {editable: false, type: "number"},
    TransactionAmount: {type: "number"},
    TransactionTime: {type: "date"}
  }
```

For the field TransactionTime I have a column defined like this:

```
{
  field: "TransactionTime",
  editor: transactionTimeColumnEditor,
  format: "{0:u}"
}
```

The field editor is a DateTimePicker:

```
function transactionTimeColumnEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDateTimePicker({
      format: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
      timeFormat: "HH:mm"
    });
}
```

The grid data source transport is defined as following:

```
create: {
  url : "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AddDeposit", "AdminDeposit"))",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: addAntiForgeryToken
},
parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
  if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {
    data.TransactionTime = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data.TransactionTime, "G"));
  }
  return data;
}
```

Controller so far does nothing:

So far my controller does nothing:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddDeposit(DepositTransactionModel model)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageOrders))
            return AccessDeniedView();


        return new NullJsonResult();
    }
```

In the controller I see the TransactionTime value isn't populated. When I check raw HTTP POST parameters I see such string:

```
Sun+Jan+22+2017+22:52:39+GMT+0100+(Central+Europe+Standard+Time)
```

As you can see I tried to convert TransactionTime property of the form data to standard format. However it didn't help. Inside parameterMap function data.TransactionTime looks like this:

```
Date 2017-01-22T22:03:31.708Z
```

but HTTP POST param still looks like above.

Also I tried to set Kendo culture:

```
kendo.culture("@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name");
```

Result is still same.

I read about another option - setting transport as functions and send manually generated JSON to the server. However I would like to avoid extra complexity on the client side.

Do I miss anything important?

Comment: please mention code for your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found a solution. Not sure why it works but it does.
I have implemented parameterMap function of data source transport that TransactionTime is converted to UTC string:

```
parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
  if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {
    data.TransactionTime = data.TransactionTime.toUTCString();
  }
  return data;
}
```

That's it